# Good design? Smart pointers for allocation combined with raw pointers for access

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, smart-pointers

I'm designing a `FilterData` class that reads in a custom binary data file and builds a data model of it in memory. I want to allocate all memory using smart pointers and let this `FilterData` have ownership of the data. When a caller needs access to the data, it will just get a raw pointer from the `FilterData` instance.

Do you think this is good design or would you find this "mixture" confusing as a programmer?

Some thoughts:

1. *Why raw pointers?* I need to interface with existing APIs that use raw `float*`. Furthermore I emphasize the caller does not own the allocated memory. Most of my "clients" are coders who are not so experienced in handling smart pointers.
2. If I ever need a copy of the data, I can extend `FilterData` with corresponding functions that return `std::unique_ptr` with a copy (therefore transferring ownership of the copy).
3. As a possible danger I see that someone could call `delete` on the returned pointer, but since I plan on doing all memory allocation with smart pointer, any `delete` would be erroneous anyway.

Here's some example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class FilterData
{
  using fvec = std::vector<float>;
public:
  FilterData(const std::string& filename) {
    // (simulate read from file...)
    m_filterACoeffs = std::make_unique<fvec>();
    m_filterBCoeffs = std::make_unique<fvec>();
    m_filterACoeffs->emplace_back(1.f); m_filterACoeffs->emplace_back(2.f); m_filterACoeffs->emplace_back(3.f);
    m_filterBCoeffs->emplace_back(-1.f); m_filterBCoeffs->emplace_back(-2.f); m_filterBCoeffs->emplace_back(-3.f);
  }
  const fvec* getFilterACoeffs() { return m_filterACoeffs.get(); }
  const fvec* getFilterBCoeffs() { return m_filterBCoeffs.get(); }

private:
  std::unique_ptr<fvec> m_filterACoeffs;
  std::unique_ptr<fvec> m_filterBCoeffs;

};

int main() 
{
  FilterData filterData("thefile.bin");
  auto p_filterACoeffs = filterData.getFilterACoeffs();
  auto p_filterBCoeffs = filterData.getFilterBCoeffs();

  std::cout << "Filter A is: " << p_filterACoeffs->at(0) << " , " 
                               << p_filterACoeffs->at(1) << " , " 
                               << p_filterACoeffs->at(2) << std::endl; 

  std::cout << "Filter B is: " << p_filterBCoeffs->at(0) << " , " 
                               << p_filterBCoeffs->at(1) << " , " 
                               << p_filterBCoeffs->at(2) << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: Raw non-owning pointer is ok (as long as lifetime is correct). `std::share_ptr`/`std::weak_ptr` might give more guaranties.

Comment: In your example, returning references seems more appropriate Btw.

Comment: IMHO it's a topic for code review

https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: `std::vector<float>` is not the best example to use with `std::unique_ptr`, as `vector` is enough by itself.

Comment: For working code / review; please post on: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd have overloaded `operator[]`. You can always convert an instance of class overloading operator[] to pointer via &instance[0] assuming all elements are contiguous in memory.

Comment: As other already say: prefer references over pointers, also avoid exposing internals of classes (I know, it is an example).  But to answer your question somewhat: avoid having to pass smart-pointers around, they limit the usability.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I fully agree about the references, makes the intent even clearer.
And you are absolutely right - I should have posted on codereview. Sorry about that! What's the proper etiquette here? Repost there and delete this question?

Comment: It's an important question, but should be generalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use and expose unique_ptr when ownership is the be transferred. Use shared_ptr when ownership is to be communal. Define functions to take raw pointers or references iff they do not participate in ownership.

In your case, use unique_ptr but do not expose it or a method to access it. You did that, so good on you. Expose the raw pointer, constified as necessary, and if someone wants to call delete on it, hey, it's their foot they're aiming at. I would have preferred exposing the raw pointer in a way that required less typing.

This talk from CPP Con 2014 nails it: https://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64?t=12m10s (I know links are evil, but I suspect this one will live until the statue of Liberty is chest deep in sand.)

Comment: Thanks for the link - it seems I was on the right track :-)